# When to save time-series data

Tags: database, time-series

We're collecting market data on about 30,000 financial instruments.  We want to keep historical data for every 10 minutes or so.  It's all saved in a PostgreSQL table.  I am debating between two approaches:

### "Snapshot"

Store price of all symbols every 10 minutes, with nice round timestamp.

Advantages:

- Makes querying easy, since timestamp is known *a-priori* just by rounding to last 10-minute multiple.

Disadvantages:

- Larger data set
- Large inserts will affect performance
- Won't convey how often instrument data changes without storing additional information

### "Rolling Updates"

Store each symbol only when it is updated, if time elapsed since last update is longer than 10 minutes.

Advantages:

- Fewer and smaller (cheaper) inserts
- Smaller data set
- Data will more closely reflects actual frequency of changes (for instruments which change less than once every 10 minutes)

Disadvantages:

- Queries will be more complex/expensive because timestamp of desired row isn't known.

### Considerations

- We have many more inserts than queries
- We will want to be able to scale to significantly more instruments, possibly slightly higher frequency updates.

I have been doing "Rolling Updates" and I don't see any performance problem with the queries.  There is only a single multi-column index on the table, but inserts still seem to be much more expensive than queries, so this seems to be the better-suited method.  Is this a reasonable approach?  Are there other considerations I am missing?

Comment: Which option did you take and why? What is the db for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm re-implementing our feed and I'm switching from rolling updates to snapshots.  It was easier to code; I don't have to keep track of when to store what.  The data are loaded into a carefully indexed PostgreSQL table using binary copy, so insert performance isn't an issue; we're seeing rates of at least a few thousand records/sec, which is sufficient.

I am not using specifically round timestamps, but that would make it even easier to *retrieve* the entire snapshot, should we want to do so.  At this point, we only retrieve data for one symbol at a time, at a single point in time.

Most of the symbols we deal with change much more than once every 10 minutes, so in any case our data set doesn't reflect the frequency of change in these symbols.

**Update:** We've started making more extensive use of the historical data.  The ease with which we can now retrieve larger blocks of data for a single point in time is a real boon.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with the snapshot approach that arise from the fact that not all instruments will tick on every minute, specially since you are considering a universe of 30,000 instruments which must include some instruments with lower liquidity that may trade unfrequently.

The rolling updates approach has the problem of having timestamps all over the place, which may complicate things when querying the data.

A third approach that combines them both works best, you keep a temporary record of the "rolling update" for all instruments in-memory on your parser, and on the 10 minute mark you write the latest value to the permanent table and reboot the temporary records. This approach also makes it easy to keep track of Open, High, Low, Close and Volume values.

Comment: Actually, yes.  Since we do most of our work with the current data, there is a separate table in the database for that.  The fact that updates on some instruments are infrequent isn't a problem per se.  It just means that in order to simplify retrieval, we have more data than would otherwise be theoretically necessary.

Comment: The snapshot approach shouldn't have significantly more data than the rolling one... In both cases you are saving a data point (Im guessing OHLCV) for each instrument every 10 minutes. Unless Im missing a part of the picture? 

If anything, I would be inclined to store all the raw messages or to generate the data snapshots with the smallest granularity possible (like 1 minute), since this will make a change in the size of the time window trivial... a trader suddenly deciding that you need to move to 5 or 15 minutes wouldn't mean going back to square 1, just running a script.

Comment: The snapshot certainly has more data.  As you pointed out, with snapshot we save all instruments at every interval, but some change very infrequently.  With rolling updates, those would be saved much less often.

Comment: I saw that you on your linkedin that you guys trade options, they can be pretty slow specially as you move away from the money. Since they are ticking unfrequently, why not save every raw record and then aggregate them using a batch process on a Lambda architecture? With tools like SPARK or STORM you could have the info you need, and the flexibility to move the analysis in a different direction in the future.